# How can i create a single QR code from more value cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub setQR()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2018/8/22
    Dim xSRg As Range
    Dim xRRg As Range
    Dim xObjOLE As OLEObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xSRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the cell you will create QR code based on", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xSRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xRRg = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to place the QR code", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xRRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xObjOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("BARCODE.BarCodeCtrl.1")
    xObjOLE.Object.Style = 11
    xObjOLE.Object.Value = xSRg.Text
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(xObjOLE.Name).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
    xObjOLE.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the above code return a QR code for the text in the selected cell? Do you have Kutools for Excel installed? If so, what do you mean by "more value cells"? To select more such cells in the first `InputBox` and obtain the QR code for concatenated value of each selected cells?

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification question in the above comment...

So, if you have Kutools for Excel installed and want creating a QR code from the value of (more) selected cells (in the first `InputBox`), try the next adapted code:

```
Sub setQR()
'Updated by Extendoffice 2018/8/22
    Dim xSRg As Range, xRRg As Range, strText As String, cel As Range
    Dim xObjOLE As OLEObject
    'On Error Resume Next
    Set xSRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the cell you will create QR code based on", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
     If xSRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     For Each cel In xSRg.cells
        strText = strText & cel.Value 'building the concatenated string from selected cells range. The range can be discontinuous, too
     Next
    
    Set xRRg = Application.InputBox("Select a cell to place the QR code", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    
     If xRRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set xObjOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("BARCODE.BarCodeCtrl.1")
     xObjOLE.Object.Style = 11
     xObjOLE.Object.Value = strText
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.item(xObjOLE.name).Copy
     ActiveSheet.Paste xRRg
     xObjOLE.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for help. Why does the the ASCII encoding for the TAB function not work if i insert ~d009 after a number? Exemple 10087~d009 it generate a scanned qr code with all the values including ~d009 :(

Comment: @Denis Cristian Harapcea I cannot get you, I'm afraid... 1. **How do you "insert"**? 2. If you need to add the `Tab` character you should use `vbTab`, but it is also important **how you "insert" it**... 3. ASCII character for `vbTab` is 9. You can test that using `Debug.Print vbTab`. it will return 9 in `Immediate Window`... 4. If I try connecting somehow your comment to the question and you want using Tab as separator between cells value, you should use: `strText = strText & vbTab & cel.Value`. If you need something else, it would be good to better explain what you try accomplishing, I think.

Comment: @Denis Cristian Or if you are in love with ASCII code, (in VBA) you can use: `strText = strText & Chr(9) & cel.Value`...